# Dimension of a space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, cardinals

I'm reading a book about Hilbert spaces, and in chapter 1 (which is supposed to be a revision of linear algebra), there's a problem I can't solve. I read the solution, which is in the book, and I don't understand it either.

**Problem:** Prove that the space of continuos functions in the interval (0,1): $C[0,1]$, has dimension $c=\dim(\mathbb{R})$.

**Solution**: The solution of the book goes by proving that the size of a minimal base of the space $B$ is first $|B|\leqslant c$ and $|B|\geqslant c$, and so $|B|=c$. the proof of it being greater or equal is simple and I understand it, the problem is the other thing. The author does this:

> A continuos function is defined by the values it takes at rational numbers, so $|B|\leqslant c^{\aleph_0}=c$

I don't get that.

Comment: Hmm, interesting that the book apparently assumes the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Could you please develop that answer. I'm very interested in it. I just don't get that equality.

Comment: It was just an observation (the continuum hypothesis is that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\aleph_1$). It is strangely stated anyway, since it mentioned $\rm{dim}(\mathbb{R})$ but not over what field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That was actually added by me under complete ignorance. I deleted it.

Comment: What is a minimal basis?

Comment: @julien It maybe a mistraslation from spanish, I translated it literally and probably the english word is different: it's a base that generates the full space, but whose members are linearly independent.

Comment: But generating + linearly independent = basis. I don't see what minimal has to do here. Probably it is rather minimal generating family.

Comment: @julien That's the teqhnical name. In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the vectors $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,0)$ generate the space, but they're not "our" minimal basis because you can remove one of the vector and still have a basis.

Comment: No, your four vectors are not a basis since they are not linearly independent. Again, basis=linearly independent+generating. A basis is a minimal generating family. Note that it is also a maximal linearly independent family.

Answer (score 4):

Since the rationals are dense in the reals, a continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to  \mathbb R$ is completely determined by its values on the rationals. Thus, the the function from the set of all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to the set of all functions $g:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ (continuous or not), given by restricting a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ to the rationals, is an injective function. Thus the cardinality of the former is less than or equal to the cardinality of the latter, which is $|\mathbb R|^{|\mathbb Q|}=c^{\aleph_0}=c$.

The question is concerned with the domain $[0,1]$, but there is no essential difference.

Comment: Where can I see a proof of $c^{\aleph_0}=c$?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if $f$ and $g$ are two functions in $C[0,1]$ and the restrictions to $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ of $f$ and $g$ are equal then $f$ and $g$ are actually equal.

This is a simple consequence of the density of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ in $[0,1]$ using the continuity of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f,g$ are continuous and for every rational number $q$ it holds that $f(q)=g(q)$ then $f=g$ everywhere.

This means that $|B|\leq|\mathbb{R^Q}|=|\mathbb{R^N}|=|\mathbb R|$.

Also, $|\mathbb R|$ is not necessarily $\aleph_1$. This assumption is known as the **continuum hypothesis**.